# Searching a map with upper bound and lower bound

Tags: c++

STL newbie question:

Regarding functions `std::map::upper_bound` and `std::map::lower_bound` is it valid to specify a key that is not actually present in the map?

Example

```
std::map<int,int> intmap;
std::map<int,int>::iterator it1, it2;

intmap[1] = 10;
intmap[2] = 20;
intmap[4] = 40;
intmap[5] = 50;

it1 = intmap.lower_bound (3);  // Is this valid?
it2 = intmap.upper_bound (3);  // Is this valid?
```

Comment: Yes. (15 chars)

Comment: billz gave a better explanation on this.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes, they are both valid.

[`map::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound) returns an iterator pointing to the first element that is not less than key.

[`map::upper_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/upper_bound) returns an iterator pointing to the first element that is greater than key.

```
intmap[1]=10;
intmap[2]=20;
intmap[4]=40;   // <<---both lower_bound(3)/upper_bound(3) will points to here
intmap[5]=50;
```

`lower_bound/upper_bound` return the position where **value would get inserted.**

Note, If you want to check the value key is map or not, you could use [std::map::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find)

Comment: @bilz can we do mp.lower_bound(k) - mp.begin() i.e. find count of elements with their key less than k similar to what we do with array. If not, why?